$n$th term expression for sequence $1,x,\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{3},\frac{x}{4},\ldots$
I would like to find the general $n$th term expression for
$$1,x,\frac{x}{2},\frac{x}{3},\frac{x}{4},\ldots,$$
since the first term is $1$ instead of $x$, I can't write $a_n=\frac{x}{n}$. However, for the numerator, I think of $x^{H(x-1)}$, where $H(x)$ is the unit step function, but for the denominator, I am stuck, there seems not a function that satisfies $1,1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$.

$\frac{x}{n-1}$ is your function. But the $f(0)$ is constant and provided by the question. It's not a part of the series. Its just added there. I'm sure you have a clear idea of how $\frac{1}{t}$ works as it approaches zero. The value would be bigger and bigger and at zero its infinity if we look from only the positive end.

*Typo. At $n=1$ I meant. Not $f(0)$.

As Gwen said in the comment, you basically need a hybrid function:
$t_{1}=1$ and for $n>1, t_{n}=\frac{x}{n-1}$.

I'm not sure why you would need a single formula instead of a hybrid, but if you do, you could use $$t_n = \frac{x^{H(n-0.5)}}{n+H(0.5-n)}$$ for $n=0,1,\ldots$ and there's a lot of room to adjust this expression with the same resulting sequence.
